# Is there any replicate function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

`replicate(n:Int,x:T):List<T>`  is a list of length n with x the value of every element.

I wrote a mutable version replicate as below:

```
fun <T> mutableReplicate(n:Int, x:T) : MutableList<T>{
    val xs = mutableListOf<T>()
    for (i in 1..n){
        xs.add(x)
    }
    return xs
}
```

Is there any bulid-in immutable replicate function in Kotlin?

How to write ourselves an immutable replicate function in Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `List instantiation functions`. They accept a function from the Index to the desired element, but you can also use them to create a List of constant values.

```
fun <T> replicate(n:Int,x:T):List<T> {
   return List(n) { x }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a read-only list, you can implement `replicate` the following way:

```
fun <T> replicate(n: Int, x: T): List<T> = object : AbstractList<T>() {
    override val size: Int = n
    override fun get(index: Int): T = 
        if (index in 0..lastIndex) x else throw IndexOutOfBoundsException("$n")

}
```

It has an advantage that it requires a constant amount of memory no matter how large `n` is.